# Exchange 2010 MITM attack

Tags: security, ssl, exchange-server-2010

I have an Exchange 2010 org deployed and I am publishing owa through TMG. I have disabled SSLv1/v2/v3 and some Ciphers. But if I analyse my site with ssllabs (https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) it shows that my owa site is vulnerable for MITM attacks. My owa site is rated F now =( but, I do publish another site/app with the same certificate (Citrix Secure Gateway) and that one shows up with rate C and no MITM danger. So the MITM must be fixed in Exchange somewhere I guess, or in TMG.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks!
Grtz,
Ronald

Answer (score 1):

Well, just turning on secure negotiation did the trick, my site is now rated A-, that is due to disabled perfect forward secrecy. I have to put these fs ciphers on top and disable the others.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to get useful information from this description but I guess that the F is because the server certificate can not be validated, because either the trust chain does not fit or the name does not match or both. This would mean that a client get a security warning in the browser. If it just overrides the browsers warning without verifying the certificate in a secure way any certificate could have presented to the user, which in effect means a man-in-the-middle attack.

What you would need to fix then is to make sure that name match and trust chain can be verified with a CA trusted by the browser (i.e. no self-signed certificate and no private CA).

if you need more detailed information instead of this guessing please provide more details about the site (URL would be sufficient).

Comment: Hi Steffen, I use a 3rd party trusted cert. So the cert is fine. It is a wildcard cert and other sites using this cert show fine on the MITM vulnerability. Only owa has a problem, so the cert itself is out of the equation.This is the info:This server is vulnerable to MITM attacks because it supports insecure renegotiation. Grade set to F.

Comment: Hmm, nevermind, I had to set DisableRenegoOnServer in the SCHANNEL section. Tonight a restart will show if that did the trick.